# Validate uniqueness of email against another model's email address's

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, email, associations

I have a User model that has a "has_many" :emails association to an Email model. The user's primary email is just a column "email" for the user. However, I have this association that allows for multiple email addresses for a user.

The problem is that when a new user is created and "validates_uniqueness_of :email" is checked, it only checks other user's email column instead of possible secondary emails stored in the Email model.

I have tried to write a custom validate method in my User model that tries to find a user by the email address given and it works, but then it screws up other things in my code, like being able to add secondary email addresses or assign primary ones.

Is there a way to say something like: "validates_uniqueness_of :email through Email.all.each do {|e| errors.add :email, "this is invalid" if e.email == :email}"

This looks really sloppy, but all I'm trying to do is validate the uniqueness of the email address of a user upon creation against another model's instance's email address.

P.S. In case you are confused about the e.email, Email is the model and it has a column email that stores the email address.

Comment: Any particular reason why do you need to have `email` field in User model too?

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to write a custom validator. Something along these lines:

```
class User 

  validates_uniqueness_of :email
  validate :email_in_use

  private

  def email_in_use
    if Email.where("lower(email) = ?", self.email.downcase).first
      errors.add(:email, "There is already a user with this email")
    end
  end

end
```

I agree with @CWitty, though – you may want to consider moving the primary email address into the 'emails' table, rather than storing it straight on the User model.

Comment: Writing a custom validator is the first thing I tried, but for some reason it was affecting the functionality of adding secondary email addresses.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need to think about your schema a bit. I would remove the email column from your `User` model and instead have all of the emails stored using the association. You could add a `default` flag to the `Email` model to signify the users default email.  This would allow you to move the `validates_uniqueness_of :email` to the `Email` model and not try to check it in multiple places. Plus it cleans up your data so that it isn't in multiple places.

Comment: We added this feature not too long ago, but were are really cranking on something else so we can't go back and really spend time on it right now. Is there a little quick fix I could do in the meantime?

Comment: You could add a `before_save` hook that check that checks to see if the other table has the same email and if so return false and add an error to the model so it doesn't save.

Comment: I guess I'll try the before_save hook. I kinda wanted to avoid this as it's separate from the validators.

Comment: You can also do http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4676371/rails-validating-uniqueness-across-multiple-models